# How to auto adjust the components for Sencha Touch 2 application

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

am new to Sencha Touch 2 framework. am creating a project using Sencha Architect in that you have the option to select a device to display your views. Devices include ipad, iphone 4 and 5, Blackberry etc etc. Am creating a project as per view in iphone (320 * 480 ). My question is when i view the project in ipad simulator the components of my view screen do not adjust automatically. I want to run my project on iphone,ipad,blackberry or any android phone or tab. How can i achieve this independence so that my components on screen could adjust length, height etc etc properties at their own. Is there any way to do this by using Sencha Architect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your app architecture, you could probably use a [fit layout](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.Fit). However, the best would be to implement [profiles](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Profile), take a look at:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/profiles

Comment: Hi Nico, I think profile will only help me in finding whether the running device is phone or tab. My doubts are :- (1)Each phone and tab also have different resolutions in that case how my components will auto fit according to size of the screen. (2) If my step 1 requirement is possible can it be achieved using Sencha Architect ? if not Can you please suggest an IDE for Sencha like we use eclipse for java which gives us suggestions upon Ctrl+Space. (3) If i go by profile way do i need to code separately for phones and tabs ?

Comment: 1) That depends on each component but 99% the framework will take care of it even without the profiles.

Comment: 2) Im not an architect user but I think you can do everything with it. I personally dont use any IDE in particular, I use gedit with a lot of developer plugins. I find it excellent in my case, like many others I got to use like a dozen languages so you can code for all from the same application.

Comment: 3) Not necessary that you 'need to', is more like 'you can if you want to'. In some cases you may want a view to display different for tablets. For instance when accessing an item of a list, is normal to show only for tablets the entire list on a side panel.

Comment: Hi Nico, I will build my application using fit layout and see the results in diff simulators and emulators. however i have the only option to build application using Sencha Architect. And Also if fit layout does not work for me i will create diff views for mobiles and tabs. Thanks